# Limit the coil's voltage of the stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor

When the step motors are used with a current-controlled driver, also known as a chopper drive. The driver will increase output voltage when the motor runs much faster, because the faster the motor runs, the larger reactance the motor's coil has, the larger voltage is required to maintain a constant current.

I think it will destroy the motor when the motor runs extremely fast in this fashion, its coil's current keeps constant but the voltage is increased without limit, the resulting power dissipation will be very large.

Should I limit the coil's voltage according to the "rated voltage" in the motor's datasheet?  So when I use current-controlled driver with its current set to the motor's max phase current, the motor can't run much faster when the motor's coil voltage reaches the rated voltage.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

It's the current in the windings that creates heat. The voltage does not matter in that context. As long as the current does not exceed the specifications it should be OK.

Comment: +1. Also, if motor speed is a concern, don't step it so fast - **you** have control of that.